# Magento2 images for indevedual Store like example.com base, small, thumbnail image not get selected in programmatically adding images to the products

Tags: magento2

I am adding images to the products from a folder programmatically using addImageToMediaGallery function. below is my controller code

```
<?php
namespace Kammalou\AddMissingImages\Controller\Missing;
use Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory;
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context;

class Images extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $pageFactory;
    public function __construct(Context $context, PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {        
        var_dump(__METHOD__);
        $page_object = $this->pageFactory->create();
        $obj = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $productCollection = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory');
        $collection = $productCollection->create()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->load();
    
    

        foreach ($collection as $product){
            $productId =  $product->getId() ; // Id of product
            $product = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
            $image = $product->getImage();
            if($image =='' || $image=='no_selection' ){
               // echo 'Name  =  '.$product->getName().'<br>';

                $imagePath = "/var/www/vhosts/m2atimedev/httpdocs/var/inriver/pics/".$product->getName().".jpg";                                                                                          
                // path of the image
                //echo $imagePath;exit;
                if(file_exists($imagePath)){
                    //Remove Images From Product
                    
                    $productRepository = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface');
                    $existingMediaGalleryEntries = $product->getMediaGalleryEntries();
                    if($existingMediaGalleryEntries){
                        foreach ($existingMediaGalleryEntries as $key => $entry) {
                            unset($existingMediaGalleryEntries[$key]);
                        }
                    }
                    $product->setMediaGalleryEntries($existingMediaGalleryEntries);
                    $productRepository->save($product);

                    // Adding Image to product
                    $product = $obj->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($productId);
                    $product->addImageToMediaGallery($imagePath, array('image', 'small_image', 'thumbnail'), false, false);
                    $product->save();
                }
                //echo 'image  =  '.$product->getImage().'<br>';

            }
        }

        return $page_object;
    }
}
```

The code is working very fine. but the problem is when images are set as thumbnail only for default magento scope. In the store scope image is showing but not selected as thumbnails.
[image]

when i change scope, the base small thumbnail image does not show selected.
[image]

As a result in the frontend the images are not showing with the products on category and search results page.
[image]

If we click on products with missing images, than on the product page images is showing correctly.

How to show images with products on category page programmatically. Right now i have to go to backend, select product, change scope to store and set base, small and thumbnail image.

Comment: does it throw any exceptions if not is the path correct??

Comment: if(file_exists($imagePath)){   is already added in the code for that purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have just a simple solution .I hope it work for you .
On table `catalog_product_entity_varchar`

```
$tableName = 'catalog_product_entity_varchar';
$productId = '1';
try {
            $getimage = "SELECT value FROM " . $tableName . " WHERE `entity_id` = '$productId' AND `store_id` = '1' AND `attribute_id` = '85'";
            $imageUrl = $connection->fetchAll($getimage);
            $imagePath = $imageUrl[0]['value'];
            $sql = "DELETE FROM " . $tableName ." WHERE `entity_id`='$productId' AND `attribute_id` IN ('85','86','87')";
            $connection->query($sql);
            $sql1 = "INSERT INTO " . $tableName ." (`attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES ('85','0','$productId','$imagePath'),('85','1','$productId','$imagePath'),('86','0','$productId','$imagePath'),('86','1','$productId','$imagePath'),('87','0','$productId','$imagePath'),('87','1','$productId','$imagePath')";
            echo $sql1;
```

}

Where 85,86,87 are code for base,small and thumnall resp. (for my case).

before run You should backup database and check that codes.

Answer (score 0):

Some products who’s images were not showing have this kind of problem.
to search thumbnail images

```
SELECT * FROM catalog_product_entity_varchar WHERE entity_id = 9676;
```

[image]

you can see for the website with id 1 the images records have saved  “.jpeg” instead of .jpg and for default storeID 0, it was not the problem.
So  i changed jpeg to jpg using below query:

```
UPDATE catalog_product_entity_varchar SET value = REPLACE(value, '.jpeg', '.jpg') WHERE attribute_id IN (85,86,87);
```

I Run below query to change base small  and thumbnail images from  storeID 0 (default veiw) to storeID 1(example.com)

```
UPDATE IGNORE catalog_product_entity_varchar set store_id=1 WHERE attribute_id IN (85,86,87) AND store_id=0;
```

Problem was base small  and thumbnail images  were set for default view but not for example.com store view